# Asking jquery array format

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these two forms of array. Here is a captured form of the arrays:

[image]

It seems that there is no difference between them, but the problem occurs when I am using `$.inArray()` in jQuery, The second form array always give result `-1` when I am searching value `1`

Can you give me an explanation please?

Comment: second array you are testing is empty array . pls check,

Comment: Yes... Never rely on console. The second array is getting data after console is executed. That's why you see [] and when you expand, it displays the latest value

Answer (score 0):

i think your array contains integer values and you try to search as string that's why it return -1

```
 var arr=[1,1,1,1]
 console.log(JQuery.inArray('1', arr )) // return -1 

 var arr=[1,1,1,1]

 console.log(JQuery.inArray(1, arr )) // return 0
```